# Do people commonly say "go down" to mean "go to sleep"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I saw this in a movie (Joe Swanberg's [Happy Christmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Christmas_(film))).

> "How long has he been sleeping for?"
>
> "He went down right at 1:00"

I have never heard the phrase used like this, and can't find this meaning in dictionaries.

Is this usage common?

Comment: It's not common, but I've heard it before. Again, it is not very common and would be an idiom.

Comment: What movie? Who was "he"? This might have been used when a baby or toddler takes a nap. "She put the baby down for a nap."

Comment: @user3169 It's Joe Swanberg's _Happy Christmas_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Christmas_(film)  Since the dialogue was completely improvised, I assume it's closer to everyday speech? And you are right on the mark! They are talking about a baby.

Comment: What @user3169 said. I would not say this when referring to my teenager, but I would use the expression for a baby or toddler. I think it’s generally used when the person sleeping is young enough to be told when to go to sleep, or go down for a nap.

Comment: Yes, only used for a baby. I should have said that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be kind of careful when using **down**.
When putting a baby to sleep, one might say

> I **put** him/her **down** an hour ago.

on the other hand, to say

> I **put** the dog **down**.

means the dog has been euthanized.

For people

> **go down**

usually is understood to mean some form of **oral sex**.
This is a situation where surrounding **context** is very important.